# Error while cloning Thunderbird's Mercurial repository

Tags: repository, mercurial, clone, thunderbird

I wanted to clone the Mozilla Thunderbird repository to my PC.

I used the official guide ([here](https://developer.thunderbird.net/thunderbird-development/getting-started)) and tried to clone several times, but after a few minutes it always throws an error.

there is always the same following error message:

```
abort: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
transaction abort!
rollback completed
[Code 255]
```

I used this command for cloning:

`hg clone --verbose https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central "C:\Users\...\source\"`

(userpath shortened)

Comment: I just tried this and got a slightly different error. It ran for a while and got close to completion, but eventually died with `abort: stream ended unexpectedly  (got 6858 bytes, expected 32768)`

Comment: looks like it means the same

Comment: maybe it is different because i ran it over the GUI

Comment: I think this means there's a problem with the repo itself? I think you should find out how to ask them.